# Issue in sorting multidimensional vector in java

Tags: java, sorting, vector

I have a multidimensional vector in java, which I need to sort. When I print the vector in console it is getting printed as given below.

```
[[1,Sundeep,place1],[2,Arun,place2],[3,Vivek,place3]]
```

I need to sort the vector according to the second item, ie, the name. So that the vector should look like:

```
[[1,Arun,place2],[2,Sundeep,place1],[3,Vivek,place3]]
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You have to post some code in order for people to check what is wrong with the algorithm

Comment: That doesn't look like sorting. Your example shows that the vectors don't contain the same values before and after. So what are you actually trying to achieve? And why don't you use objects?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard sort functionality with a custom comparator and have the comparator look at the second item.

Really this data design is bad though `[1,Sundeep,place]` should be fields in an object.

Comment: In the "code sample" only the second entry gets rearranged. The others stay untouched. I don't know why he wants this behaviour, but it makes the Comparator-approach impossible.

Comment: @aRestless True, although that could be just mistakes in how he's displaying it in the question. If he wants an ascending index in the data he can always loop through and put that back after.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check that.

Comment: Then you can use the comparator approach and afterwards a loop to set the indexes if you really need that. Honestly your data design is badly flawed though.

Answer (score 1):

I would also start with a Class like "Place" where you encapsulate your fields.

```
public class Place {

    private int position;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Place(int position, String name, String type) {
        this.position = position;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * @return the position
     */
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * @param position the position to set
     */
    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return position + " " + name + " " + type;
    }

    public String printContentWithoutPosition() {
        return name + " " + type;
    }
}
```

Then i would suggest to create a Comparator, which helps you sorting your List like this

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class OrderByName implements Comparator<Place> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Place o1, Place o2) {

        int retVal = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        if(retVal > 0) 
            return 1;
        if(retVal < 0)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And now lets try it

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
        places.add(new Place(1, "Sundeep", "place"));
        places.add(new Place(2, "Arun", "place"));
        places.add(new Place(3, "Vivek", "place"));

        Collections.sort(places, new OrderByName());

        for(Place place : places)
            System.out.println(place);

        int i = 1;
        // here you iterate through your places and print the current position
        // if you need it like you show in your question.
        for(Place place : places) {
            System.out.println(i++ + " " + place.printContentWithoutPosition());
        }
    }

}
```